# FatalErrorException in PropelBundle.php line 29: Compile Error: Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle::boot(): Failed opening required

Tags: propel, symfony-2.7, propel2

Im trying to use propel ORM with sympfony v-2.7

In my composer I've added this line

> "propel/propel-bundle": "^1.4",

and installed this package successfully.

Then I load the Bundle into my karnel using this

```
$bundles = array(

    new Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle(),

        );
```

My config.yml settings

```
propel:
path:       "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/propel"
phing_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/phing"
logging:    %kernel.debug%
dbal:
    driver:               %database_driver%
    user:                 %database_user%
    password:             %database_password%
    dsn:                  %database_driver%:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%;charset=UTF8
    options:              {}
    attributes:           {}
```

But when I try to access-  http://localhost/my-serp/web/
I got this Error

```
FatalErrorException in PropelBundle.php line 29:
Compile Error: Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle::boot(): Failed opening required 'D:\wamp\www\my-serp

\app/../vendor/propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php' (include_path='D:\wamp\www\my- serp\vendor/phing/phing/classes;D:\wamp

\www\my-serp\vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib;D:\wamp\www\my-     serp\vendor/propel/propel1/generator/lib;.;C:\php\pear')


in PropelBundle.php line 29
at PropelBundle->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2414
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2442
at Kernel->handle() in app_dev.php line 28
at {main}() in app_dev.php line 0
```

I follow the documentation from github, can anybody say me what i've missed ??

Answer (score 0):

Check/change your propel path to:

```
path:       "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/propel/propel1"
```